# "I counted with that", is it correct in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I heard very little about count with:

> Count with me" means that we both say "1... 2... 3... 4..." at the
>   same time.

I have an equation and I'm saying to myself `"Yes, I counted with that"` meaning I didn't forget to include a certain variable in my calculation.

With this meaning, I suppose `Count with me` could also mean "Include me into your plan".

Can I use it that way? If not, what would you say in my place?

**EDIT:**

The meaning I seek is: `be aware of and take the appropriate action/precaution/..`

- [...] that tomorrow we leave early. (So I should not forget to prepare myself for early exit)
- He's leaving in two weeks, [...] . (So I should talk or do anything with him while he's still here because I should be aware he's leaving)
- I [...] the velocity so the result is correct. (Saying that I was aware of the velocity and so I calculated it correctly)
- [...] that I will go with you. (Make sure you don't forget to include me as well)

**EDIT (after a few years):**
I should rephrase the question like this:
Often I tend to use the word "count" when in my mind I'm thinking, doing some calculation or reckoning.

Best way to put it: I counted with {something} being on my mind, hence I want to just shorten the phrase, not having to always say "being on my mind" at the end.

For example:
I'm in the middle of cooking dinner. Woman comes in and says: Do you realize we are going to a restaurant tonight? Yes, I counted with that, but {some clever answer}.

---

Given this explanation, the "with" is used correctly (with something being on my mind). Which makes me wonder why is it still so wrong?

Comment: No. "Take account of", but the verb "count" is not used in those ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common phrases to use in different situations:

I'm aware of that
I understand (that)
I realize (that)
I considered that
I took that into account

E.g I considered/was aware of/... the velocity, so the result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

"Count with me" basically means "Let's count together/at the same time." "Count" is a verb in the imperative tense, and "with me," is a prepositional phrase. You could also say to someone, "Eat with me," meaning, "Let's eat together/at the same time." You could also say to someone, "Skate with me," meaning "Let's skate together/at the same time." You can use this construct with lots of active verbs.

I have never heard someone say in reference to an equation "Yes, I counted with that." If I wanted to communicate that I didn't forget a certain variable in my calculation, I might say, "Yes, I included that," but it would depend on the context.

"Count with me" doesn't mean "Include me in your plan." There's the idiom, "Count me in!" which I think better expresses what you mean to say. "Count me in!" basically means, "I want to be included in what you're doing!"

Comment: Can you take a look at my edited question, please?

Comment: Actually I thought of "take into account" which seems good to me. I wonder if "allow" can also be used somehow. I thought I could say "count" in the sense of making a calculation (with that variable in mind).

Comment: @DanielK - I think “take into account” is what you may be looking for. Indeed, one might say, “Yes, I took that into account.” (Perhaps you heard that once and assumed the person said, “Take that into a count.”)

Comment: @J.R. Not really, I thought count also means to make a calculation (.."with" something in mind). Calculate would perhaps work too but maybe not so common?, as in "I calculated with that". Because when you calculate with something, you are aware of it and act based on that information.

Comment: @J.R Oh, actually, "be aware" is what I sought.

Answer (score 1):

We are organising a trip in the car.  Someone asks, “What about the dog?”  I reply, “I counted the dog with the children.”  That means that I put the dog in the same category [group] as the children.

Suppose that we are counting our stock, and someone asks me why I got 56 for a type of part, when they can see that there are about 25.  I say, “I counted with the plastic ones included.”  That means that the other person was only thinking of the metal ones.

You don’t say “Count with me.”; you say “Include me in your counting”.  For your example about an equation, where you say, “Yes, I counted with that.”… you would say, “Yes, I did include that.”

( [Duplicating “mlecoz”.]  “Count me in!” means, for instance, “I want to come too!”.)

“I counted on him being there.” means that it has turned out badly because he was not there.  (It does not mean • that he *did*, nor • that he *did not*, know that I was counting on his being there [or “him being there”].)

“I am counting on you!” means that I need you to do what we decided you would, and otherwise everying will go awry [badly].

I can say, “I am banking on them not realising what is going on, until the door opens.”… to mean that I expect that they will not realise {whatever it is}, and that, if they do realise, my plan will fail.

“Remember that tomorrow we are leaving early.”
“Keep in mind that we are leaving early, tomorrow.”

“He is leaving in two weeks, so you need to keep that in mind.”
“He is leaving in two weeks, so we need to plan accordingly.”
“He is leaving in two weeks, so after that it will be too late.”
“He is leaving in two weeks, so you need to get it done by then.”
“Just be aware that he is leaving in two weeks.”
“He is leaving in two weeks, so make sure that you do not tell anyone before then.”
[I need more context, for this.]

“I included the velocity, so the result is correct.”
“I calculated the velocity using the [fancy maths term] equation, so the result is correct.”
[Actually, you would say, “… the result *should be* correct.”]
“I realised that the velocity is squared, in this case, so… .”
“I was aware that… .”
“I remembered that… .”
“I know that we are supposed to do this using the [fancy maths term] method, because of the [] being 0, so I used the linear velocity equation.”

“Don’t forget that I want to be there when you talk to him.”
“Don’t forget that I need to go with you to the shop.”

“I am depending on you to be there by 5pm.”
“I am depending on the train being a few minutes late.”
“It all depends on how the weather is over the next few days.”
“It [the plan] all depends on the English not making it through to this bridge until after sunset.”

Less common:
“His calculations [plot] depended on John talking to Mary before the concert.”

Comment: What I meant all along was "I counted with something being on my mind" hence I asked about "I counted with that". Does it make sense? Thanks for revisiting this question! :-)

Comment: “I marked the papers with {the fact that the fire alarm went off in the middle of the exam} in mind.”  Is this the idea?

Comment: I updated the question with a good example and a bonus question. I'll tick off the answer which will answer the bonus question. I might know the answers now myself. I should just say "I realize that", "I know that", "I considered that". where "consider" also quite fits with the previous examples I'd given.